# How can I query for all selinux rules/default file contexts/etc affecting a type

Tags: linux, security, selinux

I need to know everything related to a selinux type on a **running system's current rules**:

- allow, allowaudit, dontaudit rules.
- files labeled with a context using the type.
- transitions.

...and any other info.

Is there any command(s) I can use to query for that info or should I download the all selinux related "src" packages, filter out the modules not in use and grep every file for that info? There must be an easier way to do that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some of the commands to obtain this info are (examples use `httpd_log_t`):

1. `seinfo`

   ```
   # seinfo -x --type=httpd_log_t /etc/selinux/default/policy/policy.26
      httpd_log_t
         file_type
         non_security_file_type
         logfile
   ```
2. `sesearch`

   ```
   # sesearch --dontaudit -t httpd_log_t /etc/selinux/default/policy/policy.26 | head
   Found 35 semantic av rules:
       dontaudit run_init_t file_type : dir { getattr search open } ;
       dontaudit staff_t non_security_file_type : file getattr ;
       dontaudit staff_t non_security_file_type : dir { ioctl read getattr lock search open } ;
       dontaudit staff_t non_security_file_type : lnk_file getattr ;
       dontaudit staff_t non_security_file_type : sock_file getattr ;
       dontaudit staff_t non_security_file_type : fifo_file getattr ;
       dontaudit unconfined_t non_security_file_type : file getattr ;
       dontaudit unconfined_t non_security_file_type : dir { ioctl read getattr lock search open } ;
       dontaudit unconfined_t non_security_file_type : lnk_file getattr ;
   ```
3. `semanage`

   ```
   # semanage fcontext -l | grep httpd_log_t
   /etc/httpd/logs                                    all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0
   /var/log/apache(2)?(/.*)?                          all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0
   /var/log/apache-ssl(2)?(/.*)?                      all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0
   /var/log/cacti(/.*)?                               all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0
   /var/log/cgiwrap\.log.*                            regular file       system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0
   /var/log/horde2(/.*)?                              all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0
   /var/log/httpd(/.*)?                               all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0
   /var/log/lighttpd(/.*)?                            all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0
   /var/log/piranha(/.*)?                             all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0
   /var/www(/.*)?/logs(/.*)?                          all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0
   ```

References: [RHEL6 SELinux manual](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/ch05s11.html)

Comment: is there any way to know which modules use a specified type? i.e. how to connect that info to the loaded selinux policy module (semodule -l)?

Comment: OK, I will reduce the scope of the question to mark this answer as accepted and separate the first aspect to another question.

Comment: @YankoHernándezÁlvarez believe it or not, I've trying to figure that out. I've post my findings in you other question.

Comment: For those looking, that other question is [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/521668/how-to-match-selinux-rules-transitions-labels-etc-to-modules).