# How to match selinux rules/transitions/labels/etc to modules

Tags: linux, security, selinux

I need to match [running/loaded selinux rules/transitions/labels/etc](https://serverfault.com/questions/521078/how-can-i-query-for-all-selinux-rules-default-file-contexts-etc-affecting-a-type) to the selinux policy modules where they are defined (semodules -l). I need this because I want to study some selinux policy modules in context and I need to know which ones I should check.

Is there any easier way to do that than to download all selinux related "src" packages, filter out the modules not in use and grep the resulting files for that info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, there's not a way to do that. It might be related to the fact that the policy a machine is using is **compiled** from the modules, which only exist in the source code:

```
# file /etc/selinux/default/policy/policy.26
/etc/selinux/default/policy/policy.26: SE Linux policy v26 MLS 8 symbols 7 ocons

# file -i /etc/selinux/default/policy/policy.26
/etc/selinux/default/policy/policy.26: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

The very detail of what module included what rule is lost after the compilation step.

However, and given that you want to study *some* SELinux policy modules (as in *some specific modules*), you can do the other way round, and either:

1. Install the `refpolicy` package for your distribution. It contains the source code (yes, not what you asked for, but probably the easiest way)
2. Extract all the information from a compiled **policy package file**. You can find these files in `/etc/selinux/$policy/modules/active/modules/*pp`. A very detailed explanation on how to decompile a module has already been posted [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/321301/how-do-i-view-the-contents-of-a-selinux-policy-package).

Comment: ok, thanks. "It's not possible" is also an answer ;-) I have already seen #2, but I think it doesn't worth the effort, so I will go to the source.

Comment: /etc/selinux/$SELINUXTYPE/modules does not exist any more.

Comment: it moves to /var/lib/selinux/$SELINUXTYPE/active, but there is no pp file instead there are cil, hll and lang_ext. there is no tool seems be able to revert it to source