# How to inspect the rules in a policy module?

Tags: selinux

I know I can use `semodule -l` to see what modules I have. However, I want to see the rules contained in a specific module.

I read almost all document I can find for semodule, seinfo, sesearch. I cannot find any way to do this.

If it is possible can anyone show me how to do this?

If it is impossible can anyone explain me why it has to be so difficult? Isn't this a common practice to check what kind of rules are allowed in others' modules?

Especially if we allow rpm to carry policy modules, how would you know it is not something harmful?

When I find some string rules in there, I want to know who to blame.

**update**

I researched more, inspired by [this](https://serverfault.com/a/521703/417610) post I found in new OS there is `/var/lib/selinux/<store>/active/modules/<priority>/<module_name>/{cil,hll,lang_ext}`

according to [document](https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux/wiki/High-Level-Language-Infrastructure):

> The HLL data, cached CIL data, and HLL extension are stored in /var/lib/selinux//active/modules//<module_name>/{cil,hll,lang_ext}. The lang_ext file contains the extension of the HLL (with no newline), which is used to determine the file in the compiler directory to execute to compile the HLL data to CIL.

It seems the hll is actually a copy of .pp file. However, it is not.
if I try to use semoudle_unpackage or sedismod on the hll file it throws.

```
libsepol.module_package_read_offsets: wrong magic number for module package:  expected 0xf97cff8f, got 0x35685a42
semodule_unpackage:  Error while reading policy module from /var/lib/selinux/targeted/active/modules/.../hll
```

So till now I still do not have any solution for this.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/321301/how-do-i-view-the-contents-of-a-selinux-policy-package

Comment: I certainly aware of this post. But it is completely different. I want to know the rule of already installed module not from a .pp file. but thanks anyway. please unvote your close.

Comment: hi @Wang did you manage to solve this issue ? I also have a file with the same magic as you : `0x35685a42`

Comment: ok so I found out that this little endian (`0x35685a42`) is the magic big endian (`xxd|head` 
 output): `0x425A68` AKA `BZh` which is bzip2 magic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)

Comment: and `bzcat file_cil_that_is_actually.bz2` output a correct selinux CIL file for me

Comment: thanks, maybe you want to post an answer @Boop

Comment: so what you mean is I can bzcat hll | sedismod?